# Raman spectra of peptide

Tags: spectroscopy, raman

This is my first time measuring Raman spectra of a peptide sample. It is in solid form. I do think I see some Raman peaks but I am not sure how to assign them. I have a peptide sequence through which I can make tentative assignments but I can't pinpoint which one belongs to which amino acid. This is due to the possibility that there could be more than one contender for a given peak/band.
I would be grateful if someone could help me out or point me to some other source/reference I could lookup.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Peak assignment in spectroscopy is not a trivial task especially for a large molecule. I am not an expert in this area but you should consult someone who can do modelling for you and try to predict its spectra.